# Blank space in between Bootstrap centered columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, spacing

I want to add blank space in between this two columns, and I have tried the padding way with inner , used offset, etc. I can't figure it out.

I am not fuzzy about the amount of space, just that it is clear that there are two columns.

Another important thing, I want it to be centered in the screen. I've been able to get the blank gap with it not being centered, but that doesn't work for me.

http://www.bootply.com/eUwlCeISme#

Thank you!

Comment: please post relevant code here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a margin to make some whitespace on the sides of the columns, which you cannot do with `display: table-cell`. Use something like `display: inline-block` for `.row2` instead, apply a margin to `.row-centered` like `margin: 0 2px;` or something, and then use a different method to keep the column heights the same, for example `min-height: 225px;`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/92D6S.png